# change the text to uibutton in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I have a mistake with change the text to uibutton in iOS

```
@interface ViewControllerSonidos : UIViewController{
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *initgame;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *initgame;
- (IBAction)Reproducir:(id)sender;
```

And my implementation file looks like this:

```
@implementation ViewControllerSonidos
@synthesize initgame

- (IBAction)Reproducir:(id)sender {
    [initgame setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

but the problem is that the text is never changed, somebody looks what is wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are You sure that the UIButton is connected to IBOutlet?

Comment: Did you check to see if the method was actually called?

Comment: its working for me .can u post the whole code

Comment: yes, the UIButton is connected, and the method performs other code when is taped

Comment: can u show the xib and .h together

Comment: Please add `NSAssert(initgame, @"initgame is nil!");` to you IBAction and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways you can do this.

- You can just connect it with the IBOutlet,
- you can use it with id sender
- or you could just use the simple IBAction signature

examples:

```
 // using the id sender method
 - (IBAction) buttonTitleChange:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle: @"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

 // using the connection one
 - (IBAction) buttonTitleChange: (id)sender {
    //AFTER CONNECTING THE BUTTON IN .XIB
    [buttonName setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

 // and the regular void method....also requiring the linkage of the .xib
 - (IBAction) buttonTitleChange {
    [buttonName setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

just remember to connect the button in .xib for them all

using the id sender, just says that you can use it for any type object. the id sender with connection is just a way of writing the method, and the regular method is just a way of practice.

It all depends on how you program.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
- (IBAction)Reproducir:(id)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: thanks but I try this code but the result is the same, the text is not changed

Comment: you connect methode of Reproducir in xib ?

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with `IBOutlet` ,you forgot to connect it in XIB otherwise it'l works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)btnChanged
{
    [m_btnSample setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: i suppose u need to check the outlets are connected properly or not.and if not try creating a button programatically and then check if the btnAction is catually been called.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)initgame:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *initgame;
@end
```

in ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)initgame:(id)sender {
[self.initgame setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
}
```

don't forget to attach button from .xib to property and IBAction.

**if It doesn't work now, just remove the connection between the Button and IBAction/Property, create new IBAction and property for it and it will work for the above code.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes please check IBOutlet connection, because same code worked for me.